# T-SQL query trying to sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, database-administration

I have the below script (all using System Databases).

Below is my script. It's basically a script to identify SQL Server Agent jobs which are running longer than 240 minutes.

```
--Step 1: Decide if anything is actually running longer than 240 mins
IF EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT      p.spid, 
                j.name, 
                p.program_name, 
                ISNULL(DATEDIFF(mi, p.last_batch, GETDATE()), 0) AS MinutesRunning, 
                p.last_batch
    FROM        master.sys.sysprocesses AS p 
                INNER JOIN sysjobs AS j 
                ON dbo.udf_SysJobs_GetProcessid(j.job_id) = SUBSTRING(p.program_name, 32, 8)
    WHERE     (p.program_name LIKE 'SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep (Job %') AND (ISNULL(DATEDIFF(mi, p.last_batch, GETDATE()), 0) >= 240)
    )



--Step 2: Set the variable format and define a query
DECLARE @longjob NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @longjob = 
'SELECT     p.spid, 
                j.name, 
                p.program_name, 
                ISNULL(DATEDIFF(mi, p.last_batch, GETDATE()), 0) AS MinutesRunning, 
                p.last_batch
    FROM        master.sys.sysprocesses AS p 
                INNER JOIN sysjobs AS j 
                ON dbo.udf_SysJobs_GetProcessid(j.job_id) = SUBSTRING(p.program_name, 32, 8)
    WHERE     (p.program_name LIKE ''SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep (Job %'') AND (ISNULL(DATEDIFF(mi, p.last_batch, GETDATE()), 0) >= 240)'




--Step 3: Execute the email and set content
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail            
@profile_name = N'SERVER',          
@recipients = 'EMAIL', 
@subject = 'SUBJECT',
@body = 'TEXT',
@query = @longjob,
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1;
```

My aim is to trigger an email only when there are long running jobs - but an email currently seems to be sent each time it runs (with blank results) .

Comment: try qualifying `sysjobs`  like `msdb.dbo.sysjobs`

Comment: That's done the trick, thanks. I hadn't fully qualified in both locations (only one). But now finding issues with the IF EXISTS part i.e. an email is triggered even when no results are found.

Comment: If **you** tag it as `database-administration` - it really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** and therefore it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...

In my case, *IF COUNT > 0* worked better than *IF EXISTS*.

```
    IF  
        (
        SELECT      COUNT(*)
        FROM        master.sys.sysprocesses AS p 
                    INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS j 
                    ON msdb.dbo.udf_SysJobs_GetProcessid(j.job_id) = SUBSTRING(p.program_name, 32, 8)
        WHERE     (p.program_name LIKE 'SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep (Job %') AND (ISNULL(DATEDIFF(mi, p.last_batch, GETDATE()), 0) >= 240)
        ) > 0

    BEGIN
...
snip
...
    END
```